# DVD writer not working

Tags: windows-xp, dvd-burning

I have a LG DVD Writer  which has worked fine for the two years. But now it has started behaving like CD Writer i do not able to read or write DVDs. but i am able to read and write cds in the same . So my question is that is it a software problem in my computer or the dvd writer get faulty ? As it read/write CDs i think it should not the problem of DVD Writer.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling drivers. If that doesn't help, detach your DVD writer and connect it to any other PC. If PC#2 recognizes it as a DVD writer, then it's software problem, or you might need to replace the data cables...

Comment: i am able to read/write CDs so does it be a hardware problem ?

Comment: Told you, try to reproduce issue on another PC with the same DVD writer. If it fails r/w again, it's the hardware problem. Otherwise, double-check your drivers & cables :)

Comment: I agree with other members - I forgot about the laser head cleaning! Try that 1st!!! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's probably been while since you cleaned the dust off the laser lens.  Open the drive door and blow air vigorously into the drive.  You can use a can of compressed air or you can use your own lungs and a drinking straw.  You would be surprised how often this simple remedy will bring an old drive back to life.

Answer (score 0):

@Hemant you know the answer of this problem. As you told that you are using this dvd write since two years.

This is problem occurs with some DVD writers that they stop reading DVD but do all work with CD. *Definitely your DVD RW have hardware issue.*

> CD burning/reading uses a different laser, so CDs may work, but DVDs
>   fail if the DVD laser is dead. You could try cleaning the laser lens,
>   but both lasers use the same lens, so not likely the problem. I would
>   consider replacing the drive.